# matching second hand cpus for dual cpu system

Tags: central-processing-unit

I have a need to replace some CPUs in an HP DL360 server (g8 or g9 I believe).  FWIW the new CPU will be V1 or V2 E5-26xx CPU's   (most likely E5-2697v2 or similar - something that gives the maximum bang for buck)

I know that I want the CPUs to be the same model, and I've read "the same stepping" - but this does not appear to be commonly specified.  Is matching MPN numbers or Ean numbers [ for Intel CPU's ] sufficient to ensure the CPU's will play nice?

Comment: There was only ever one stepping for that processor anyway.

Comment: Thinking of doing the same. Any tips of wisdom?